# NameError: global name 'Critter' is not defined

Tags: python

I wrote a simple program.

```
class Critter(object):
   def __init__(self,name,hunger=0,boredom=0):
   .....

   def __pass_time(self):
    ....

   def __get_mood(self):

   .....
   def talk(self):
    ....
   def eat(self, food = 4):
   ....

def main():
   crit_name = raw_input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
   crit = Critter(crit_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
   ("\n\npress enter key to exit.")
```

When I run the code, I encounter this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last)class Critter(object):   File
>   "D:/python/Critter.py", line 1, in -toplevel-
>       class Critter(object):   File "D:/python/Critter.py", line 75, in Critter
>       if **name** == "**main**":main()   File "D:/python/Critter.py", line 45, in main
>       crit = Critter(crit_name) NameError: global name 'Critter' is not defined

Can you please explain the cause of error and also give a solution.

Comment: Could you edit your post to have the exact formatted code. It seems to be a formatting issue.

Comment: It is working for me. Can you check question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an indentation problem here, may be this is what you wanted to do:

```
    class Critter(object):
        def __init__(self,name,hunger=0,boredom=0):
        .....

        def __pass_time(self):
        ....

        def __get_mood(self):

        .....
        def talk(self):
        ....
        def eat(self, food = 4):
        ....

    def main():
        crit_name = raw_input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
        crit = Critter(crit_name) 

    if __name__ == "__main__":main()
    ("\n\npress enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Thanks @Khalil. Program is running without error but I don't get output.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Critter(object):
   def __init__(self,name,hunger=0,boredom=0):
       print "init"

   def __pass_time(self):
       print "__pass_time"

   def __get_mood(self):
       print "__get_mood"

   def talk(self):
       print "__talk"

   def eat(self, food = 4):
       print "eat"

def main():
   crit_name = raw_input("What do you want to name your critter?: ")
   crit = Critter(crit_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
   ("\n\npress enter key to exit.")
```

This works fine, Can you copy paste and check?